# What word can be matched with 'general calculation'?

Tags: vocabulary

My electronic calculator, a Casio, has this abbreviation in it, **COMP**.
It is supposed to be thought as 'general calculation mode,' unlike vector calculations etc. But I've not yet found what word the maker would have based on for the abbreviation. Can you tell me the word for the meaning?

Comment: I believe that it's reasonable to think of this *COMP* as "compute", though I couldn't find a piece of evidence that Casio really shorten "compute" to *COMP*. On [this page](http://support.casio.com/answer.php?rgn=5&cid=004002002001&qid=24368&num=2), it writes "COMP: Basic arithmetic calculations". In [this document](http://support.casio.com/storage/en/manual/pdf/EN/004/fx-82_85_95_350ES_PLUS_EN.pdf), it writes "When you want to perform this type of operation: General calculations, perform this key operation: [MODE] [1] (COMP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COMP button is a short form of Compute.

I'm not an engineer and not so good at math as well! And thus, don't know the functionality but at least [this document shows it](http://www.tvmcalcs.com/calculators/sharp_el_733a/sharp_el_733a_page1)

Answer (score 2):

"COMP" is probably short for "compute".